# Is there a solid way to get a user's IP, despite them being behind a proxy or similar?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, proxy, ip

I've searched for this quite a lot but the answers are not always clear.

Is there a solid way to get a user's IP address despite them being behind a proxy, tor, etc?
Preferably using ASP.NET

I just cannot imagine "big sites" like Google, Hotmail/Outlook not having some relatively reliable way of bypassing these things, especially since they (atleast hotmail/outlook) require you to use Javascript.

Comment: If there was a way to get a user's real IP address when they were using a good proxy or Tor, what would be the point of using either? You can *detect* Tor users by checking if their IP address is in the public list of exit nodes. For arbitrary proxies, good ones are indistinguishable from regular users, as they don't send any extra information.

Comment: Requiring JavaScript doesn't make any difference because JavaScript doesn't have access to that information (thankfully). Not sure about Java or Flash.

Comment: What makes you thing "big sites" must have some relatively reliable way of bypassing these things? Being worth a bazillion dollars doesn't give you magic powers.

Comment: I understand all replies you have given me so far, but that doesn't really explain why Javascript seems to be such a "privacy risk" to most people. Note, I've read this on other websites discussing the use of Javascript.

Comment: @Kevink: Because JavaScript engines are the most common source of identity-exposing security holes in browsers.

Comment: That does make sense. However, they speak of javascript "tricking" people into revealing their true IP... That doesn't seem like using a security hole.

Comment: @Kevink: Browser fingerprinting is another reason, but I've never heard of "tricking" users into giving up information. Take a look at this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40620/why-is-javascript-disabled-in-the-tor-browser-bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there was a way to get a user's real IP address when they were using a good proxy or Tor, what would be the point of using either?

- You can *detect* Tor users by checking if their IP address is that of [an exit node](http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/). There aren't that many. You *cannot* get their actual IP address without exploiting some browser bug or hoping they use Flash or Java. Most Tor users don't use any browser plugins and disable JavaScript.
- Some proxies send `X-Forwarded-For` headers, so you can catch users using bad proxies. Good ones are indistinguishable from regular users, as they don't send any extra information.

If you are trying to prevent bots, remember that most bots just send and receive HTTP requests. They aren't browsers. Your best bet is detecting bot-like behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess it would be a bit too easy.. I'm guessing X-Forwarded-For isn't very reliable if it only works on bad proxies. I'll just have to "block them out" as best as possible, then.

Comment: @Kevink: What exactly are you trying to block?

Comment: The "utopia" would be to just block out everyone who tries to connect through any sort of proxy. That's possible to a certain extent with the link you provided.. but unfortunately ofcourse not all.

Comment: Thanks for your time & informative explanations. It's a shame there is no solid solution to people abusing proxies to access services etc, but I guess with there being such a large amount of options to choose from it's nearly impossible.

Comment: @Kevink: But why would you want to block people using proxies? Not everyone uses proxies for evil.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to unmask someone's IP behind a proxy unless you have some relationship with the proxy.

However sometimes HTTP proxies add a header line "X-Forwarded" which identifies the real source IP address.

Hope this helps.